# How to control a google compute engine instance of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I have used this image on GCE to build an instance of wordpress VM

[image]

After the instance is created, here is some of the data I find on the instance's web page:

[image]

I use a combination of these meta data but I am not able to login to the `phpmyadmin` page

[image]

What is the right way to start with a wordpress server that is setup this way?  Is there any documentation? What username/password pair in the 'Custom metadata' section is applicable to the phpmyadmin?

**Edit**:

Attempted login/password combinations:

- `WORDPRESS_ADMIN_EMAIL`/`WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD`
- `WORDPRESS_ADMIN_EMAIL`/`WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD`
- `WORDPRESS_ADMIN_EMAIL`/`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

Comment: What is Anthony in the screenshot? Have you tried logging in as root with the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD?

Comment: 'anthony' above comes from the `WORDPRESS_ADMIN_EMAIL` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the wordpress database via `phpmyadmin`, use username `wordpress_user` and the password in the field `WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD`

The wordpress console can be accessed via '/wp-admin'. Use `WORDPRESS_ADMIN_EMAIL` and `WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD` to log in

[image]

More details of the wordpress setup can be found in the script `/opt/c2d/wordpress-setup.sh`

`c2d` stands for 'click to deploy'

Answer (score 0):

As per one of the comments, if you are trying to log in phpMyAdmin to administrate the database server, you must use root / MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

Instead of looking for this information in the VM's metadata, it is easier to identify it by going to Cloud Console -> Deployment Manager -> "Your Wordpress deployment"

All the passwords and usernames are listed there in a more comprehensible view (Wordpress username/password phpMyadmin username/password).